# Jquery slide from right working in fiddle but not on the live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have sliding content (a menu which is for mobile).

I have it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/NfXTY/7/ where the content is not visible at first and then slides in from the right, then goes back to sliding right and hidden.

The problem I'm having is that on the site it slides in from the left still which I don't get because my fiddle works just fine?

Edit: Updated below code on the site

The JS:

```
jQuery('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
    var $marginLefty = jQuery('#navigation');
    $marginLefty.animate({
        right: parseInt($marginLefty.css('right'), 10) == 0 ? -$marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
    });
});
```

The CSS:

```
#navigation {
background-color: #44CC55;
bottom: 0;
color: #333333;
height: 36px;
right: -350px;
padding: 6px;
width: 338px;
position: absolute;
```

}

Comment: instead of `left` you need to use `right`?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gres4/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Thanks for helping again, I'll try once more. Did you check out the site in question? Do you see any other issues?

Comment: nothing that come to notice now.... try it let us know

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I just updated the site in question with the code in your fiddle but it's still not working :( now the slide out doesn't show at all..

Comment: where is the code added? in which file

Comment: http://forthebetter.com.au/wp-content/themes/RAC/includes/js/general.js?ver=3.6

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38137/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-dt-dtdg)